# Is java.math.BigInteger's usage wrong?

Tags: java, biginteger

I play around with java.math.BigInteger. Here is my java class,

```
public class BigIntegerTest{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     BigInteger fiveThousand = new BigInteger("5000");
     BigInteger fiftyThousand = new BigInteger("50000");
     BigInteger fiveHundredThousand = new BigInteger("500000");
     BigInteger total = BigInteger.ZERO;
     total.add(fiveThousand);
     total.add(fiftyThousand);
     total.add(fiveHundredThousand);
     System.out.println(total);
 }
}
```

I think the result is `555000`. But the actual is `0`. Why ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`BigInteger` objects are immutable.  Their values cannot be changed, once created.

When you call `.add` a *new* BigInteger object is created and returned, and must be stored if you want to access its value.

```
BigInteger total = BigInteger.ZERO;
total = total.add(fiveThousand);
total = total.add(fiftyThousand);
total = total.add(fiveHundredThousand);
System.out.println(total);
```

(It's fine to say `total = total.add(...)` because it's just removing the reference to the *old* `total` object and reassigning it the reference to the *new* one created by `.add`).

Comment: @PeterLawrey sure, if you know you only need 63 bits for your values ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 BigInteger fiveThousand = new BigInteger("5000");
 BigInteger fiftyThousand = new BigInteger("50000");
 BigInteger fiveHundredThousand = new BigInteger("500000");
 BigInteger total = BigInteger.ZERO;

 total = total.add(fiveThousand).add(fiftyThousand).add(fiveHundredThousand);
 System.out.println(total);
```